# How can i define type of src in tsx in nextjs

Tags: typescript, next.js, tsx, t3

```js
<Image src= { sessionData?.user.image} alt="user"   width={100}
                height={100}  />`
```

Error is :

```
Type 'string | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | StaticImport'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | StaticImport'.ts(2322)
image-component.d.ts(7, 5): The expected type comes from property 'src' which 
is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Omit<DetailedHTMLProps<ImgHTMLAttributes<HTMLImageElement>,
HTMLImageElement>, "ref" | ... 5 more ... | "srcSet"> & { ...; } & RefAttributes<...>'
```

Is There any way to give it a type or should i leave as it is becuase its not giving me any error in web page

Comment: I believe the problem is that, since you use optional chaining, the `src` prop of the `Image` component might be `undefined`, which is not accepted as the prop expects it to be a `string` or a `StaticImport` (which would be if you imported the image at the top of your file). Check whether or not the `user` key exists on the `sessionData` object (e.g. with an `if` statement) and then pass `user.image` to the `src` prop.

Answer (score 0):

`sessionData?.user.image` could be undefined (because you are using optional chaining.

Assigning `undefined` to `src` simply doesn't make sense.

So you need to test for that state and *do something different*.

What the different thing is, isn't a programming problem problem. Maybe you want to show a different image. Maybe you want to not show an image at all. Maybe something else. Maybe that's a condition that should be impossible to reach in your app (but TypeScript doesn't know that) and you want to throw a fatal exception or display an error message.

How you fix it depends on what you want to do under those circumstances. It will *likely* involve either taking a step back and adding an `if` or following the `sessionData?.user.image` expression with a [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) and providing an alternative value. This is a design decision you need to make (or pass to some other responsible person).